# python beautifulsoup truncate text between code tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm working on an IRC bot command to fetch posts from twitter

I'm using api.twitter.com which lists a page in xml format. The time of a tweet is listed as

```
<created_at>Tue Jun 04 01:12:59 +0000 2013</created_at>
```

I want to get just the first 10 characters in between the tags.

I've tried

```
time = soup.findAll('created_at')[:10]
```

but that returns an error.

Answer (score 3):

Find all would return list of tags `created_at` in your document. When you slice it, you are slicing this list of tags and not the text within the tag ( I doubt the slicing in itself would have given you an error. Also, when you mention error, do say what that error is!).

You can verify this by doing:

```
time = soup.findAll('created_at')
type(time[0]) # returns <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

One possible way how you can do what you want:

```
time = soup.created_at.string[:10]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve it. I didn't realize I was slicing the tags and not the text, makes sense now. Cheers.